# fineOneAndUpdate error with typescript: Property 'findOneAndUpdate' does not exist on type 'Document<any, any>. for mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB database setup and i'm trying to sort based on username and then update the passwordHash variable with a new password. I'm having an issue with typescript giving me the error mentioned in the title. Here is my code so far:

```
let update;

    switch (key) {
      case "Student":
        const newStudent = new Student({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          username,
          passwordHash,
          facultyID,
          admissionYear,
          semester,
          enrolledCoursesId,
        });

        update = await newStudent.findOneAndUpdate(
          { username },
          { passwordHash }
        );
        break;
      case "Teacher":
        const newInstructor = new Instructor({
          username,
          passwordHash,
        });

        update = await newInstructor.findOneAndUpdate(
          { username },
          { passwordHash }
        );
        if (!update) {
          return res.status(401).json({ errMsg: "Not Done brother" });
        }

        break;
      case "Admin":
        const newAdmin = new Admin({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          username,
          passwordHash,
          coursesId,
        });

        update = await newAdmin.findOneAndUpdate(
          { username },
          { passwordHash }
        );
        break;
      default:
        console.error("Please Enter the a valid user key");
    }
```

Above is the code used to update based on username (switch case is for key variable that differentiates between user types)

```
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, require: true },
  lastName: { type: String, require: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  passwordHash: { type: String, require: true },
  admissionYear: { type: Number, default: 2021 },
  semester: { type: Number, default: 20 },
  enrolledCoursesId: { type: Array, default: [0] },
  facultyID: { type: String, default: "60cc8205111a71a2f67da38e" },
  grades: { type: Array, default: [] },
});

const Student = mongoose.model("student", studentSchema);

export default Student;
```

above is my mongoose schema.

When testing with Insomnia, the request keeps going on forever and never ends. Also, fineOne() seems to work fine but fineOneAndUpdate() is giving me the error shown above in the title.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling findOneAndUpdate on the new document? You should call that on the model. Like Student.findOneAndUpdate. You would ideally want to call something like .save() with your new document.

Comment: Hey @TusharShahi Thanks a lot. Your suggest worked and now the function is working fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tushar Shahi I realized that I was making a new empty model and then trying to access it instead of accessing my current established model. Thanks a lot @Tushar Shahi